# Can I make an org-mode link that open a magit-status buffer to a specific directory

Tags: emacs, org-mode, magit

I've been using org-mode to make a shortcut file so I can easily open files in emacs that I use a lot.  But now I'd like to easily be able to open up a magit-status buffer for partiular repositories. Is there a way to make links in org-mode that will open those up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a link of type `elisp`:

```
[[elisp:(magit-status "/my/repo")][magit status for my repository]]
```

Comment: This is great -- is there a way to stop it from asking for confirmation in a popup to run the elisp code?

Comment: You can set `org-confirm-elisp-link-not-regexp` to something that matches "safe" elisp code.

Comment: Ok - I don't really understand that, and google searching didn't reveal much.  I guess I can just ask a separate question for this...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently now it's possible to use a link of type **orgit**:

```
 [[orgit:/path/to/repo][magit status for my repo]]
```

This link type and 2 others (orgit-log and orgit-rev) are provided by [orgit package](https://github.com/magit/orgit).